Kubernetes Pod to Pod communication via ClusterIp - Connection: close
Why does Kubernetes overrides and sets the HTTP response header as Connection: close for pod to pod communication via ClusterIp service. This behavior is resulting in a new connection creation and thereby response slowness on critical applications.
Is there a way this behavior can be changes without any issues?

Do you have a [mre]?  I don't think Kubernetes normally inspects the contents of TCP streams at all, and I wouldn't expect it to insert HTTP control headers like this.

@DavidMaze Connection: keep-alive is returned if the ingress URL is used instead of the ClusterIp, as well when the application endpoint is invoked directly. Please suggest if this behavior with ClusterIp can be verified?

K8s does not modify headers, it simply sets up the networking and lets the networking stack work deal with it. What do you mean "endpoing invoked directly"? The behavor via ingress would be different because ingress itself is a separate service, and and head would apply to client-ingress traffic, not to ingress-service traffic.

Do you have a minimalist deployment to verify that? Cant imagen that k8s modify http headers.

Agree that @Marc, working on to see if Connection: close is from the underlying pod itself

when you working with Kubernetes and it sets the HTTP response header as "Connection: close" for pod-to-pod communication via ClusterIP service, it's basically telling each connection to close after one request and response. This is not ideal for critical applications.
One approach is to use a headless service
Another option is to look into tweaking the HTTP client or server settings within your pods to ensure they support persistent connections (keeping the connection alive). (Connection: keep-alive header.)
